# How to set Defender Exclusion in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-11, windows-defender

I need to set folder exclusion for defender using powershell. The problem is that folder has dot in its name `../.m2/..` (folder for IDE IntelliJ IDEA). If I am trying to create this exclusion with this command:

```
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%HOMEPATH%/.m2"
```

defender takes it as file exclusion not as path, check this screenshot
[defender exclusions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGwmb.png)

I have tried different modifications of command which I have mentioned above but still same problem

```
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%HOMEPATH%\.m2"
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%HOMEPATH%\\.m2"
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%HOMEPATH%\.\.m2"
...
```

Could someone help me, how to do it?

Comment: Try `$env:HOMEPATH` instead of `%HOMEPATH%`